# successively loading a folder full of csv files without naming using a php script in Mac Terminal

Tags: php, loops, csv, terminal, directory

I'm planning to run a php program from Mac Terminal.  I have a folder on my desktop with around 800 .csv files and I need to write a php program that reads through and reads each one so that I can run some transformations on the data it's storing.  I know how to parse the .csv once it's loaded but I'm wondering if there is a way to load each file without having to name it explicitly?  I don't have a list of the 800 file names but I feel like there has to be a way to just read in all the files in a folder in a loop or something without having the title of each file listed -- I don't have much coding experience, so forgive me if there's an obvious answer of which I'm oblivious.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can PHP's glob() be made to find files in a case insensitive manner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract Data from a CSV File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php/2805486#2805486)

Comment: even without any coding experience: please use the search function before asking please.

Comment: I did try finding the answer via searching, which has worked for a lot of my questions.  With this, I was mostly looking for how to get all the files from a folder and I think, because, as I now realize, programmers would refer to a folder as a directory, all my searches for information about "functions for loading all files in a folder" didn't really return anything useful.  Otherwise, hopefully, I would have been able to come across the glob() and readdir() functions without having to post a question and clog up the forum.  Anyway, apologies!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few way todo this but glob'ing is very straightforward:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.csv") as $filename) {
   //do somthing
}
?>
```

Comment: I just checked out that function and it's definitely going to help with this code. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all files in a directory using `readdir()` :http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php.

Once you get the file name using [`readdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) you can parse it by either breaking the file content into an array and working with the cells by looping through the array using [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) (requires at least phpv5.3) or the old fashion [`fgetcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read through the file one line at a time. For each file create a string variable, and after line you read through and transform, simply append the modified line to this string with an end-of-line character appended as well. After reading through the entire file, simply replace the file contents of the original with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Awesome! I'll read up on those functions and that should get me started with my code.  Thank you so much! :D