# Scan directory for image files with case-insensitive manner

Tags: php, search, case-insensitive

This question was asked by someone else 3 years ago ([Can PHP's glob() be made to find files in a case insensitive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner)) , and I am still looking for a better solution using php script:

I am currently using:

```
$images = glob("" . $directory . "{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.Jpg,*.Gif,*.Png,
*.JPg,*.GIf,*.PNg,*.JPG,*.GIF,*.PNG,*.jPG,*.gIF,*.pNG,*.jpG,*.giF,*.pnG}",
GLOB_BRACE);
```

to scan images file from a particular directory and just wondering if there is a simplier alternative. I tried:

```
$images = glob("" . $directory . "{/*.jpg,*.gif,*.png/i}";
```

and apparently it didn't work.

Or else, is there a replacement for sql_regcase()?

Thanks for teaching

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you

```
$allowed = array("jgp","png", "gif");
$images = glob($directory, "*.*");
$images = array_filter($images, function($a) use ($allowed){
     $ext = substr($a, strrpos($a,"."));
     return in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed");
});
```