# How to ignore case in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing a webpage in php and part of my code is:

```
$files = scandir( '../www/media/' );
$fileTypes = [
  'pdf'   => 'text', 
  'jpg'   => 'text',
];
```

The problem is that if `scandir` finds a file that ends in "JPG", because of the case difference it won't be placed in `$fileTypes`. Is there a way to ignore the case difference so I don't have to type out the variations for lowercase and uppercase?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Comment: How is `$fileTypes` going to be used? If you're in control of that code, you could use `strtolower` (or `mb_strtolower`) when comparing.

Comment: where's the part of the code that actually involves the file name?

Comment: Various options while processing: `strtolower()`, `stristr()`, or `/i` or [Can PHP's glob() be made to find files in a case insensitive manner?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2520612)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignoring case, why don't you just use `strtolower()` to convert your endings to lowercase. Keep in mind, on a unix server `.jpg` and `.JPG` are NOT the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to `strtolower` the extensions of your file before insert it into your array?...

```
strtolower('JPG') == 'jpg'
```