# Counting JPG files from folder

Tags: php

im looking a better way to count how many images are in a folder, im using this script:

```
$direccion = "/var/www/XXXX/XXX/XXX/httpdocs/images/helo/";

if (glob($direccion . "*.jpg") != false)
{
 $filecount1 = count(glob($direccion . "*.jpg"));
}
else
{
 $filecount1 = 0;
}

if (glob($direccion . "*.jpeg") != false)
{
 $filecount2 = count(glob($direccion . "*.jpeg"));
}
else
{
 $filecount2 = 0;
}

if (glob($direccion . "*.JPG") != false)
{
 $filecount3 = count(glob($direccion . "*.JPG"));
}
else
{
 $filecount3 = 0;
}

if (glob($direccion . "*.JPEG") != false)
{
 $filecount4 = count(glob($direccion . "*.JPEG"));
}
else
{
 $filecount4 = 0;
}

$conteodefotos = $filecount4 + $filecount3 + $filecount2 + $filecount1;

echo $conteodefotos;
```

But this will not count if the extension has mix capital letters, like "file.JpG"

Is there a simple and more eficient way to do this?

Comment: It's an old link but this seems to answer the question.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$images = glob($direccion . "*.[jJ][pP]{[eE],}[gG]", GLOB_BRACE);

echo $images ? count($images) : 0;
```

Comment: @Vulcan - That's not a regex. `glob` doesn't take a regex. It uses its own limited pattern system.

Comment: whats the use of `,` between e and g?

Comment: @DevZer0 - It makes the `e` optional. Check out [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) on the `GLOB_BRACE` flag.