# PHP - Case insensitive File Search

Tags: php, glob

I need to check the image folder for adding some product images. My product list array has SKUs such as `a48be25, A48be29, A48BE30` and my image folder has images such as `a48BE25_1.jpg, a48bE29_2.JPG, A48BE30_1.jpg` and so on.

As you can see, the images and SKUs are mixed. I need to somehow match SKUs to the file names. If I use `glob("my/dir/{$SKU}*.jpg")`, it won't work in case sensitive operating systems according to the best of my knowledge. Is there a way to force `glob` to search in a case-insensitive way?

EDIT: I don't think this thread is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520612/can-phps-glob-be-made-to-find-files-in-a-case-insensitive-manner). I am saying this because in my case I can have many SKUs that can have mixed cases. In the mentioned thread, OP only had the word `CSV` in mixed cases, so `glob('my/dir/*.[cC][sS][vV]')` could work well there.

Comment: Have you tried the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520643/749181) to the linked question? It suggests that you fetch the filenames first, then compare them in a case-insensitive manner in a second step.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I have over 300000 images and 60000 products to add. I know I could do this but it would be too expensive isn't it? If nothing works, then I will have to take this approach. :)

Comment: @noc2spamツ I think if you have so many images then it is faster to handle this with php and don't let the filesystem do this.

Comment: @Rizier123 Could you give me an example how? Sorry if this sounds noobish. I am perplexed at this moment lol.

Comment: Is it an option to just fix the actual problem instead? So the files are NOT mixed case? Just a suggestion -- I find every time I code something like this, I end up having to do multiple versions of it for different aspects of the site.

Comment: @DragonYen I am trying to re-construct a 3 year old e-commerce system which grew up without following proper data structure ( and constraints, too). Being an IT guy, I am sure you must have already faced a project like this, or you will face it some day. No wonder I am having nightmares these days lol. No, it is not possible to fix it anymore.

Comment: Alright. Just seemed better to use the processing power ONCE (to loop the directory and either upper or lowercase all files) instead of having to do it on every display of a page. Good luck to you.

Comment: Hmm I guess this is what I am gonna do tomorrow. I am gonna take all the images and do a pattern matching. I will post my code nevertheless. Thanks :)

Comment: but this is so bad that PHP does not have a way to do this.. Seems logical to me to keep a flag to make the whole search case insensitive irrespective of the operating system.

Comment: If you were on a Windows system, then case wouldn't be an issue. Unfortunately, you're on Linux and it's a different animal altogether.

Comment: You could also try doing a batch rename to upper/lower case; that's an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ultimately ended up fetching all images from the folder and checking for each sku in the image name array.

The following code solved my problem:

```
$path = $image_path ."/*.{jpg,png,gif}";
$all_images = glob($path, GLOB_BRACE);
$icount = count($all_images);
for($i = 0; $i < $icount; $i++)
{
    $all_images[$i] = str_replace($image_path.'/', '', $all_images[$i]);
}

foreach($products as $product){
    $matches  = preg_grep ('/^'.$product['sku'].'(\w+)/i', $all_images);
}
```

Nevertheless, I would love to see  case-insensitive `glob` implemented in future.

Comment: I've been keeping this tab open lol - Glad to see you've found a solution, however a case-insensitive glob as you state, would be a worthy addition to a future PHP release. Something you can post on php.net - *Cheers*

Comment: Sorry man I can't post the C code. I am too noob for that. I am a web dev only. I hope some one does it in a future php release. :)

Comment: No problemo. I'll pass the word around though. I've a friend who knows this guy at PHP.net ;-) *cheers*